# How to get certain types of files from one server to another in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have one server called `server 1`. On this server there's a directory called `dir1`. `dir1` has 3 files in them called `neh_iu.dat_1`, `neh_hj.dat_2`, `jen_ak.dat_1`.

I need to get ONLY the 'neh' files from `server 1` to another server called `server 2`. `server 2` is where I will be performing certain modifications on these files.

How do I get ONLY the 'neh' files in Python? I'm new to python. I'm aware of a module called paramiko which allows for file transfers but assuming that there are millions of 'neh' files in `dir1`, and that I don't know the full names of all of them, how can I get an automated process for it in Python?

Comment: paramiko is a python lib for `ssh`. So let's forget python for a moment and tell us how would you go about doing it manually. SSH? FTP? NFS? Otherwise we can't give you an answer.

Comment: SSH is the method that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use python instead of bash (assuming you're on unix).

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("tar cvzf /path/to/ftp-or-static-http/foo.tgz /path/to/dir/neh*")
```

This will create a tar file with all the neh*s files. Easy to be transferred between servers (it's only one file instead of millions).
Use FTP, SFTP, HTTP or any transfer protocol supported by your server and perform a request from the other server (curl or ftp).

Comment: Can I use the above without tarring it?